# Repeatably, using the result of a function to generate a new result

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, repeat

**Example with Hashing**

Using the function SHA256 algorithm to hash the string "Hello"

```
from hashlib import sha256

print((sha256(b"Hello").hexdigest()))
```

I get the following output (result):

```
185f8db32271fe25f561a6fc938b2e264306ec304eda518007d1764826381969
```

How do I always take the new result and hash it in repeatable?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I added a example with MD5, sorry if there is confusion

Comment: I think you might want to implement a recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solution**

Example with sha256, to keep hashing the new result/outcome of the hash algorithm.

```
from hashlib import sha256

# Hashing hello
result = sha256(b"Hello").hexdigest()

while True:
    result = sha256(result.encode()).hexdigest()
    # Do something here with the result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cleartext = 'some text that I want to encrypt'
print(cleartext)
while 1:  # infinite loop
    ciphertext = myEncryptionAlgorithm(cleartext)
    print("old:", cleartext, '\n', "new:", ciphertext)
    cleartext = ciphertext
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the only difference between our answers that would allow me to evade the DV is that I keep track of whether a collision has occurred.  Other than that our answers are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
vals = {}; 
x = 'a'; 
while(True): 
    y = fake_sha(x); 
    if y in vals: break
    vals[y] = x
    x = y

print("Duplicate output found at %s, inputs = (%s, %s)" % (y, vals[y], x))
```

would <s>probably</s> work.

It keeps track of input/output pairs in a dictionary `vals`, and when a collision occurs it prints the two keys that generated the same output (the one previously stored in the dictionary and the "current" input).

All that being said, this isn't the best way to test for collisions, and implementing your own hashing algorithm isn't really advised for anything more than a learning experience.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but this looks like python 2.5 and older, do you have anything for python 2.7 and newer?

Comment: @Velocity-plus What makes you think this wouldn't work in 2.7?